# How do I write the results of a Node function to html/console log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping

I am new with node and I am trying to print the results to the console and eventually display them in HTML. I have tried invoking the function as a var that I would later use in HTML but this didn't work. Some similar example code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var x = require('x-ray')();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(x('http://google.com', 'title').write());
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the "x-ray" library, but I presume the problem is with that since it has to asynchronously make a request before it can return the response data. The documentation says that if you don't set a path as an argument to the write function it returns a readable stream, so try this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var stream = x('http://google.com', 'title').write(),
        responseString = '';
    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        responseString += chunk;
    });
    stream.on('end', function() {
        res.send(responseString);
    });
});
```

You also need to start the server listening on a particular port (3000 in the example below):

```
const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server is listening on port " + PORT + ".");
}); // the callback function simply runs once the server starts
```

Now open your browser and navigate to `127.0.0.1:3000` or `localhost:3000`, and you'll see "Google" appear!

---

**ALSO:** If you want to use the response data in a full HTML page (rather than just sending the string on its own), you may want to explore further how to do this in Express with Jade (or similar) templates. And the code at the moment scrapes Google every time someone makes a request to the appropriate route of your server; if you only want to scrape Google once, and then use the same string again and again in your server's responses, you may want to think about how to implement this (it's easy!).